# Riverpod StreamProvider, is there a way to read the previous value, within the StreamProvider itself?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using Riverpod StreamProvider to create a stream.

Within the StreamProvider, is there any way to read the previous value supplied by this same StreamProvider?

Comment: check https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/WindowExtensions/windowCount.html (or https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BufferExtensions/bufferCount.html as it has easier API)

Answer (score 0):

No.  You'll need to use a Stream filter like from the package:async pub package, or create a custom function that uses `await for (e in aStream)` to process elements as they arrive, caching the previous element in a local variable.

Edit: on second thought, you could return a stream generated by an `async *` function as the stream in your StreamProvider, which does the same thing as I just described with some input stream.